# python: import data from text

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I tried importing float numbers from P-I curve.txt file  which contains my data. however i get an error when converting this into float. i used the following code.

```
with open('C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/4e Jaar/fotonica/Metingen/P-I curve.txt') as csvfile:
    data= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '\t')
    current=[]

    P_15=[]
    P_20=[]
    P_25=[]
    P_30=[]
    P_35=[]
    P_40=[]
    P_45=[]
    P_50=[]

    for row in data:

        current.append(float(row[0].replace(',','.')))  
        P_15.append(float(row[2].replace(',','.')))
        P_20.append(float(row[4].replace(',','.')))
        P_25.append(float(row[6].replace(',','.')))
        P_30.append(float(row[8].replace(',','.')))
        P_35.append(float(row[10].replace(',','.')))
        P_40.append(float(row[12].replace(',','.')))
        P_45.append(float(row[14].replace(',','.')))
        P_50.append(float(row[16].replace(',','.')))
```

with this code i got the following error which i understand that row 2 is a string but if so then why did this error not occur for row 1. Is there any other data to import float numbers without using csv import? I have copied and pasted the data from excel to a .txt file.

returned error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/Python Scripts/P-I curves.py", line 29, in <module>
    P_15.append(float(row[2].replace(',','.')))

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I tried another following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/4e Jaar/fotonica/Metingen/P-I curve.txt', decimal=',', sep='\t',header=0,names=['current','15','20','25','30','35','40','45','50']  )

#curre=df['current']
print(current)
```

The txt file has a header and looks like this:

```
1.8   1.9  0.4     1.9  0.4     1.9  0.4     1.9       0.4
3.8   1.9  1.3     1.9  1.3     1.9  1.3     1.9       1.2
5.8   2.0  2.5     2.0  2.4     2.0  2.3     2.0       2.2
7.8   2.0  3.7     2.0  3.6     2.0  3.5     2.0       3.4
9.8   2.1  5.2     2.0  5.1     2.0  4.9     2.0       4.7
11.8  2.1  6.9     2.1  6.7     2.1  6.4     2.1       6.1
13.8  2.1  9.0     2.0  8.6     2.1  8.2     2.1       7.8
15.8  2.1  11.5    2.1  10.8    2.1  10.2    2.1       9.7
17.8  2.2  14.7    2.2  13.7    2.2  12.7    2.2      11.8
19.8  2.2  19.5    2.2  17.5    2.2  15.9    2.2      14.5
21.8  2.2  28.9    2.2  23.6    2.2  20.3    2.2      17.9
23.8  2.3  125.8   2.2  38.4    2.2  27.8    2.2      22.8
25.8  2.3  1669.0  2.3  634.0   2.3  51.7    2.3      31.4
27.8  2.3  3142.0  2.3  2154.0  2.3  982.0   2.3      62.2
29.8  2.3  4560.0  2.3  3594.0  2.3  2460.0  2.3    1075.0
31.8  2.3  5950.0  2.3  5010.0  2.3  3872.0  2.3    2540.0
33.8  2.4  7320.0  2.4  6360.0  2.4  5230.0  2.3    3880.0
35.8  2.4  8670.0  2.4  7700.0  2.4  6550.0  2.4    5210.0
37.8  NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     2.4  7850.0  2.4    6480.0
39.8  NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN       NaN
41.8  NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN       NaN
Name: current, dtype: float64
```

python seems to be returning everything instead of just line 1 which i want by printing the header current. I only want to take this line so i can save it as in an array. But How do i specifically draw the line with header current out of the data?.

I am not sure why it returned everything but i think that there is something wrong with encoding because i copied and pasted the data from excel.

Please look at the image of how the .txt looks like when copied from excel.

[image]

i tried out another short code (i also deleted the header manually for the .txt file!!), see description below:

```
data=np.loadtxt('C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/4e Jaar/fotonica/Metingen/ttest.txt',delimiter='\t')

data=float(data.replace(',','.'))


print(data[0])
```

with this code, i get the followin error.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'1,8'
```

I find this weird to occur. Is floating and replacing not enough for this

Comment: @usr2564301 i copied the data from excel and pasted into a txt file. This would save time.

Comment: Much better approach would be to use Pandas: `import pandas as pd;   df=pd.read_csv(filename, decimal=',', sep='\t')`

Comment: @Bartłomiej i approached your suggestions. But this did not return sufficient results, please see the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need omit `header=0`:

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/4e Jaar/fotonica/Metingen/P-I curve.txt', 
                decimal=',', 
                sep='\t',
                names=['current','15','20','25','30','35','40','45','50'])
```

EDIT:

```
df=pd.read_csv('ttest.txt', 
                decimal=',', 
                sep='\t',
                names=['current','15','20','25','30','35','40','45','50'])
print (df)
    current      15      20      25      30      35      40      45     50
0       1.8     0.4     0.4     0.4     0.4     0.4     0.4     0.3    0.3
1       3.8     1.3     1.3     1.3     1.2     1.2     1.1     1.1    1.1
2       5.8     2.5     2.4     2.3     2.2     2.2     2.1     2.0    1.9
3       7.8     3.7     3.6     3.5     3.4     3.3     3.1     3.0    2.9
4       9.8     5.2     5.1     4.9     4.7     4.5     4.3     4.1    4.0
5      11.8     6.9     6.7     6.4     6.1     5.9     5.6     5.3    5.1
6      13.8     9.0     8.6     8.2     7.8     7.4     7.0     6.6    6.3
7      15.8    11.5    10.8    10.2     9.7     9.1     8.6     8.0    7.6
8      17.8    14.7    13.7    12.7    11.8    11.0    10.3     9.6    9.0
9      19.8    19.5    17.5    15.9    14.5    13.3    12.2    11.3   10.5
10     21.8    28.9    23.6    20.3    17.9    16.0    14.5    13.2   12.2
11     23.8   125.8    38.4    27.8    22.8    19.6    17.2    15.4   14.1
12     25.8  1669.0   634.0    51.7    31.4    24.5    20.6    17.9   16.2
13     27.8  3142.0  2154.0   982.0    62.2    33.1    25.3    21.0   18.5
14     29.8  4560.0  3594.0  2460.0  1075.0    60.0    32.6    25.0   21.3
15     31.8  5950.0  5010.0  3872.0  2540.0   903.0    49.9    30.8   24.6
16     33.8  7320.0  6360.0  5230.0  3880.0  2294.0   387.0    40.9   28.8
17     35.8  8670.0  7700.0  6550.0  5210.0  3621.0  1733.0    71.0   34.8
18     37.8     NaN     NaN  7850.0  6480.0  4880.0  3026.0   751.0   44.6
19     39.8     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  6100.0  4240.0  1998.0   70.2
20     41.8     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  3161.0  650.0
```

---

```
#list from column 15 with all values include NaNs
L1 = df['15'].tolist()
print (L1)
[0.4, 1.3, 2.5, 3.7, 5.2, 6.9, 9.0, 11.5, 14.7, 19.5, 28.9, 125.8, 1669.0, 
 3142.0, 4560.0, 5950.0, 7320.0, 8670.0, nan, nan, nan]

#list from column 15 with removing NaNs
L2 = df['15'].dropna().tolist()
print (L2)
[0.4, 1.3, 2.5, 3.7, 5.2, 6.9, 9.0, 11.5, 14.7, 19.5, 28.9, 125.8, 1669.0, 
 3142.0, 4560.0, 5950.0, 7320.0, 8670.0]
```

---

```
#convert all NaNs in all columns to 0
df = df.fillna(0)
print (df)
    current      15      20      25      30      35      40      45     50
0       1.8     0.4     0.4     0.4     0.4     0.4     0.4     0.3    0.3
1       3.8     1.3     1.3     1.3     1.2     1.2     1.1     1.1    1.1
2       5.8     2.5     2.4     2.3     2.2     2.2     2.1     2.0    1.9
3       7.8     3.7     3.6     3.5     3.4     3.3     3.1     3.0    2.9
4       9.8     5.2     5.1     4.9     4.7     4.5     4.3     4.1    4.0
5      11.8     6.9     6.7     6.4     6.1     5.9     5.6     5.3    5.1
6      13.8     9.0     8.6     8.2     7.8     7.4     7.0     6.6    6.3
7      15.8    11.5    10.8    10.2     9.7     9.1     8.6     8.0    7.6
8      17.8    14.7    13.7    12.7    11.8    11.0    10.3     9.6    9.0
9      19.8    19.5    17.5    15.9    14.5    13.3    12.2    11.3   10.5
10     21.8    28.9    23.6    20.3    17.9    16.0    14.5    13.2   12.2
11     23.8   125.8    38.4    27.8    22.8    19.6    17.2    15.4   14.1
12     25.8  1669.0   634.0    51.7    31.4    24.5    20.6    17.9   16.2
13     27.8  3142.0  2154.0   982.0    62.2    33.1    25.3    21.0   18.5
14     29.8  4560.0  3594.0  2460.0  1075.0    60.0    32.6    25.0   21.3
15     31.8  5950.0  5010.0  3872.0  2540.0   903.0    49.9    30.8   24.6
16     33.8  7320.0  6360.0  5230.0  3880.0  2294.0   387.0    40.9   28.8
17     35.8  8670.0  7700.0  6550.0  5210.0  3621.0  1733.0    71.0   34.8
18     37.8     0.0     0.0  7850.0  6480.0  4880.0  3026.0   751.0   44.6
19     39.8     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  6100.0  4240.0  1998.0   70.2
20     41.8     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  3161.0  650.0
```

---

```
#list from column 15
L3 = df['15'].tolist()
print (L3)
[0.4, 1.3, 2.5, 3.7, 5.2, 6.9, 9.0, 11.5, 14.7, 19.5, 28.9, 125.8, 1669.0, 
 3142.0, 4560.0, 5950.0, 7320.0, 8670.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: python must have picked up something else when copying and pasting this data

Comment: If need no data like excel screen, it is in pandas not possible, for it is always used `NaN`. Check [missing data in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that no data is present, a value NaN is returned. That is correct as NaN is present in the .txt and no data is given. My goal here however is to return any row from the data imported by panda. The problem is that when i try to print out any desired row, it returns all rows.

Comment: Do you try `loc`? Like for row with index=4 `df = df.loc[4]` ?

Comment: I still did not get line 4 when using this code `df = df.loc[4]` . It prints out exactly as shown in the problem above

Comment: by adding 0's to where NaN is read, i could read the .txt file

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if understand you. If want replace NaN by 0 is not necessary add them manually, only df = df.fillna(0) working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried importing the data with pandas. unfortunately. i could not print out the 1st row or the 2nd row. i tried `print([current])` it printed out all rows including the names and blank spaces where `NaN` was assigned. So i tried opening the .txt using csv but i had to add 0 manually into the .txt file. Again, using pandas it prints out all rows instead of 1 row even if i use the command `print(['current'])`. I do not know why this happens. so does `df=df.fillna(0)` insert 0 to blank spaces in the .txt file

Comment: Ok, I think there is some data problem. So I have idea. Is possible send me your data excel or txt to my email if data not confidental? Now I am goung to bed, but tomorrow I try to find solution. Thanks.

Comment: This method works too and saves time. I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

if importing data from .txt file as csv, the missing data should be added. So in this by manually adding 0 to the .txt file and retrying this code 
with open('C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/4e Jaar/fotonica/Metingen/P-I curve.txt') as csvfile:
    data= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '\t')
    current=[]

```
P_15=[]
P_20=[]
P_25=[]
P_30=[]
P_35=[]
P_40=[]
P_45=[]
P_50=[]

for row in data:

    current.append(float(row[0].replace(',','.')))  
    P_15.append(float(row[2].replace(',','.')))

 print(P_15)
```

it works for any row to print out.